# Pointer to member of device object

Tags: c++, cuda

I know, that I should not dereference pointer to device.
But is the following an dereferencation?

```
struct example{
 int a;
 float b;
};

void test(){
 example* p_e; 
 cudamalloc(&p_e,sizeof(example));
 float* db = &p_e->b; // is this line valid?
}
```

It works on my computer, but is this valid?

edit:

With it works, I meant, that it holds in my testrun that:

```
reinterpret_cast<void*>(&p_e->b) == reinterpret_cast<void*>(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(p_e)+sizeof(int))
```

Comment: Language-lawyer probably doesn't apply, as the language purposefully don't talk about devices, CPUs, GPUs, etc...

Comment: "Works" and "is meaningful" are two different things. It works but it isn't meaningful

Comment: Yes, `p_e->b` is dereferencing `p_e` (it is equivalent to `(*p_e).b`) and you're not allowed to do that on the host. This probably "works" in the sense that it's not crashing, but it doesn't "work" in the sense of being well-defined and producing a meaningful result.

Comment: I don't understand the intention of your edit. Your code says `float db = &p_e->b;` . Did you really mean `float* db = &p_e->b;`, otherwise nothing here makes any sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding this:

```
float db = &p_e->b;
```

I can't imagine a situation where the address of an entity in C or C++ is a `float` value.  So from a language perspective, it makes no sense.  If we modify that to:

```
float *db = &p_e->b;
```

That is a sensible construct, although whether it is "useful" depends on how you intend to use it.  Taking the address of the location `p_e->b` requires taking the value of the pointer contained in `p_e` (a location in host memory, so no device dereferencing going on there) and adding to it the offset to the location `b` within the object.  That offset doesn't involve any dereferencing.  It can be computed simply by inspection of the class/structure definition.  So none of that requires any dereferencing of pointers.

The pointer that is produced (`db`) is now pointing to a location in device memory, so that pointer should only be used (dereferenced) in device code.  But you could pass that pointer by value to a CUDA kernel and make "use" of it, sensibly.

If you actually intended to populate the value `db` with the `float` contents pointed to by the pointer `p_e->b`, first of all your code does not do that, and second it would not generally be possible in host code to directly retrieve that data from the device, when the underlying base structure pointer (`b_e`) is allocated using `cudaMalloc`.

Comment: You are correct that it is no float, that was a typo. The part of the answer explaining that this is basicly adding an offset, is the important one. I suggest to remove the noise about correct use of an device pointer and the typo. Excelent answer otherwise.